# Effect on concurrency of breaking queries into multiple statements

Tags: mysql, performance, concurrency, query-performance

Let's say I have a paginated search query which takes a long time (when the offset is large) due to a large number of rows in the joined tables. The purpose of the query is to search through accounts, while also fetching whether the current user (account ID 42) has "followed" that account by doing a left join:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.nickname, IF(c.id IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL) AS `is_followed`
FROM Account AS a
LEFT JOIN Contacts AS c
ON
    c.contact_account_id = a.id
    AND c.account_id = 42
WHERE
    (a.id != 42)
    AND (a.nickname LIKE 'the%')
LIMIT 32 OFFSET 50000;
```

Is there any concurrency benefit in breaking this into 2 statements which store intermediate results in a temporary table before doing the join?

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (
  SELECT a.id, a.nickname
  FROM Account AS a
  WHERE
    (a.id != 42)
    AND (a.nickname LIKE 'the%')
  LIMIT 32 OFFSET 50000;
);

SELECT temp.*, IF(c.id IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL) AS `is_followed`
FROM temp
LEFT JOIN Contacts AS c
ON
    c.contact_account_id = a.id
    AND c.account_id = 42
```

*(The original single statement takes ~200ms, while the latter temporary table creation takes ~150ms and the subsequent join takes ~50ms. Total time remains roughly the same.)*

Does this allow `mysqld` to more easily interleave work from other connections' threads in between the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and the `SELECT`, or is this just as bad (or worse) for concurrency than a single statement that takes longer?

**Update 1**

Extended `EXPLAIN` of single-statement query:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "a",
        "type" : "range",
        "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY,nickname",
        "key" : "nickname",
        "key_len" : "303",
        "ref" : null,
        "rows" : 106880,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using where; Using index"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "c",
        "type" : "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys" : "Contact_uk_account_id,Contact_uk_contact_account_id,Contact_fk_contact_account_id",
        "key" : "Contact_uk_account_id",
        "key_len" : "8",
        "ref" : "const,a.id",
        "rows" : 1,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using index"
    }
]
```

Extended `EXPLAIN` of statements in decomposed query:

*SELECT inside CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE:*

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "a",
        "type" : "range",
        "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY,nickname",
        "key" : "nickname",
        "key_len" : "303",
        "ref" : null,
        "rows" : 106880,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using where; Using index"
    }
]
```

*SELECT from temp with LEFT JOIN*

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "temp",
        "type" : "ALL",
        "possible_keys" : null,
        "key" : null,
        "key_len" : null,
        "ref" : null,
        "rows" : 32,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : ""
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
        "table" : "c",
        "type" : "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys" : "Contact_uk_account_id,Contact_uk_contact_account_id,Contact_fk_contact_account_id",
        "key" : "Contact_uk_account_id",
        "key_len" : "8",
        "ref" : "const,temp.id",
        "rows" : 1,
        "filtered" : 100.00,
        "Extra" : "Using index"
    }
]
```

Comment: `LIMIT 32 OFFSET 50000` means MySQL has to do Traverse through 50032 rows in index (if using), before giving you just 32 rows. It is time to rethink pagination design and queries; please go through this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pagination-optimization/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I had considered moving to Elasticsearch but an approach like that is worth investigating too. Do you have any idea about the question I asked? Even if it's not a good solution to my problem, I'm interested in what effect it has on the execution of queries.

Comment: Run both the (set) of queries individually with `EXPLAIN format=json ..` and please edit the question and add the result of the explain to the question as well. In general, one query is better than two separate queries, because a query is not just about execute and fetch; it also contains other overheads like parsing, rewriting, optimizing, and analyzing various execution plans..

Comment: Unfortunately `EXPLAIN` isn't supported on `CREATE` so this information won't be very helpful for comparison. I'll focus on trying a different approach. Thanks.

Comment: @philraj - Pull the `SELECT` from that `CREATE`.  Apply `EXPLAIN` to just the `SELECT`.

Comment: @philraj - I don't think you need `LEFT`.  See if it gives you the same results with just plain `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames I've edited with the `EXPLAIN`s. The purpose of the `LEFT JOIN` is so that the column is null when an account hasn't been followed by the current user, but contains a value when the account has been followed by the current user. Otherwise I would be performing another query with the list of 32 accounts to determine which ones have been followed by the user.

Comment: @philraj - How did you get to 50000?  It is not a multiple of 32, so it seems unlikely that you pressed [Next] hundreds of times to get to this page.

Comment: There is no concurrency benefit.

Comment: How many rows in the temp table?

Comment: Well it's just an example, it's a minimal query that still represents the real one. I only put the 50000 to highlight the case where the performance suffers. In the real scenario this is being accessed by an infinite scroll on the frontend, and is causing us some occasional high DB load. The temp table has 32 rows due to the limit, but in this particular search it's retrieving them from a set of 106880 rows as you can see in the `explain`. The accounts table has on the order of a million rows.